# Local install of Google API Explorer?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Has anybody succeeded installing locally Google's open-sourced [API Explorer](http://code.google.com/p/google-apis-explorer/)?  I'm trying to use that tool to expose my company's API, and I find it difficult to get it running:  compilation required some minor code changes and library upgrades, and at runtime, some pieces of JavaScript get downloaded from different google servers etc.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to see the API by doing the following in Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63:

1. Hit the combination "Ctrl+Shift+N" to open a "New incognito window" (or use the "Customize and control Google Chrome" menu to the right of the address box)
2. Enter the URL in the "incognito" window

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer
   ```
3. After the page loads, click the shield icon that appears at the far right within the address box.
4. Click "Load unsafe script".  The API appeared.

There may be a way to configure Chrome to get past these steps but I have not found that yet.

Answer (score 0):

The opensource repository for the APIs Explorer is woefully out of date, that is partially if not entirely my own fault. I'll work on that.

That being said, the APIs Explorer is not really intended for exploring just any API. It will work well for any of Google's Discovery-based APIs, which happens to include APIs created by the new Cloud Endpoints service, recently demoed at Google I/O.

Comment: Although its been a while this topic have been raised, I was just in concern that if there would be any possibility to run this code locally. Based on your response to @vsp, you indicatated its merely based on discovery based api's. Can you think of any other open source api explorer out there, that can be easily integrated for internal use?

Thanks.